# Есть ли возможность вывести стандартную информацию об организации как в публичной части апи при клике на кастомную метку?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При клике на организацию, появляется стандартный балун карт и информация об организации проезд итд. Как вызывать этот же балун при клике на кастомную метку? или может быть можно как то увеличить значок конкретной организации на карте ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доступ к данным организации получается через [findOrganization](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization.html?lang=ru). При добавлении этой метки можно задать её кастомность (особенности метки) через **options.set**.